# Regarding fct_relevel and scale_fill_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a group of plots that represent the relationship between the product(x) and the number of consumer complaints (y). I was wondering about how to use `fct_relevel` to change the order of the plots. They are in alphabetical order right now, but I would like them to be in the calendar year order. Also, I used `scale_fill_manual` to change the color of the plot, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated!

[This is the output I have for now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk9Fv.png)

[This is the output I am looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/722vZ.png)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

cc <- read.csv('C:\\Users\\Emma Ping\\Desktop\\STAT 405\\consumer_complaints.csv')
cc1 <- cc[cc$Year == "2015" & cc$submitted_via == "Web", ]

cbPalette <- c("#CC79A7", "#D55E00", "#56B4E9", "#F0E442", "#009E73", "#0072B2", "#999999", "#E69F00")

p4 <- ggplot(cc1, aes(reorder(product, -table(product)[product]))) + 
       geom_bar() + 
       ggtitle("Number of Monthly Web Consumer Complaints for the year 2015")+
       xlab("Data Products") + 
       ylab("Number of Consumer Web Complaints")+ 
       guides(fill = "none")+
       scale_fill_manual(values = cbPalette)+
       facet_wrap(~Month, ncol=4, scales="free_y")+
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1, size=12))
p4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few built-in constants, and `month.name` is one of them. It appears that your months have the same spelling so this should work:

```
 cc1$Month <- factor(cc1$Month, levels=month.name)
```

Notice that it is not `months.names` or `month.names`.